# Google play web site isn't displayed properly on any browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, google-maps

For some reason, on Microsoft Edge, Google chrome and Vivaldy, Google play web site is not displayed properly. Please see image.

[image]

Also, Google maps is missing the part of the yellow man below, and also fails to "fly" to the requested location.

As far as I am concerned, I cleaned the browser caches, but it didn't help.

---

Also I can add something that might be related:
When I install Adobe flash player, at the end there is a message:

"Thank you and enjoy Adobe Flash Player.

Here is another product that might interest you..."

But I don't see any presented product... As if something being blocked.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Reset the browser settings..

Comment: @TechieGossip Since I don;t know how to do that for Vivaldi browser - I did that for IE, including personal data. No cure yet..

Comment: Are u using any proxy setting? Is this your Personal or office PC.

Comment: @TechieGossip This is my personal laptop

Comment: @TechieGossip Also, I now uninstalled Vivaldi and reinstalled it - with no change is results. But, as I said - the problem is not only on Vivaldi

Comment: Only you have problem with Google play site or other site also

Comment: @TechieGossip Yes, also google maps doesn't show me the down screen widgets, like for example the "Street View" yellow man, and more. Also it fails to take me to another place which I set \in the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting\Clearing hosts file fixed the problem. Unfortunately I don't know which of the hosts caused the problem, but I will add them back one by one and try to find out. According to the developers console log - gstatic looks like a main candidate...

Comment: yes because in error also when inspect it was not resolving. Does the entry was there in hosts file?

Comment: @TechieGossip yep!

Comment: I think your issue is resolved better you have to close this ticket as solved

Comment: How do I close it as resolved? I marked my answer as accepted. Is that the correct way?

Comment: And how do I cancel the bounty?

Comment: You can't. The rep from your bounty offer is removed as soon as you place the bounty.

You can choose not to award it, but the highest voted answer created after you award the bounty with at least two upvotes will still receive 50% of the bounty once it expires.

Since you added the bounty to your own question, if you accept an answer of others, it will automatically receive the full bounty once it expires if you do not manually award it.

Answer (score 2):

Lets stick to one Browser first **Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115** Check the version Update to latest one. ***Reset the Browser. Clear all cookies and cache.***

1. Go to Start(windows key) Type CMD, Right Click on CMD run  as Administrator. Run below command

> ipconfig /flushdns
>
> ipconfig /registerdns

Check the Hosts File. If you unwanted entry please delete it.

**Chrome has an option enabled by default called DNS caching/prefetching.** Let disable this.

- Go to Chrome (Customise and Control Chrome) you Find top Right hand side with three dot symbol. Go to settings
- Scroll down Last option `Advanced` Click on that setting will expand.
- In Privacy and Security settings. You Find Use A Prediction Service to Load Pages more quickly. Untick as below image.

[image: Chrome settings]

**In URL Tab of Chrome Type**

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

You get option `Clear host Cache Button`. Click on that. Prefer below image
[image: Clear Host Cache]

Restart Chrome and Try to access the Play site and Maps Site.

Comment: this would help you to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could cause this, but the 2 most obvious are
1) DNS is not resolving parts of the page
2) Something is blocking parts of the page from loading

As answers in [this previous question](https://superuser.com/q/855892/617378)  suggest, I would try [changing your DNS server setting](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#windows) to 4.4.4.4 or 8.8.8.8 Google public servers (save your previous values if they are set).

Also check your IE Connection Settings for a proxy: Under the Tools menu in Internet Explorer, click Internet Options, click the Connections tab, and then click LAN Settings.  The Proxy Server box should be unchecked.

Comment: Did both - did not help :(

Comment: It didn't occur to me you would have Google host entries in your local hosts file!  Glad you were able to fix the issue.